# Incomplete Serial RX in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, serial-port

I have a VB.NET 4 application which is receiving 10 bytes of ASCII data from a PIC24 microcontroller over UART.  This is my receive function:

```
Private Sub mySerialPort_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
        'Handles serial port data received events 
        UpdateFormDelegate1 = New UpdateFormDelegate(AddressOf UpdateDisplay)
        Dim n As Integer = mySerialPort.BytesToRead 'find number of bytes in buf 
        comBuffer = New Byte(n - 1) {} 're dimension storage buffer 
        mySerialPort.Read(comBuffer, 0, n) 'read data from the buffer 
        Me.Invoke(UpdateFormDelegate1) 'call the delegate
    End Sub
```

[Here is where I got this block of code](http://www.me.umn.edu/courses/me2011/smartprodcourse/technotes/docs/serial-port-vb.pdf)

I parse and assign the received data to where it needs to go with this code:

```
    Private Sub UpdateDisplay()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim RX_String(15) As String
        Dim RX_String_Hex(15) As String
        Dim Message As String

        For i = 0 To comBuffer.Length - 1
            RX_String(i) = Chr(comBuffer(i))
        Next
        Message = String.Join("", RX_String)
        TextBox1.Text = Message
    End Sub
```

When I launch my application, I open the serial port.  I then tell the microcontroller to send data, i.e. `1234567890`,  on my VB app it'll display things like `12`, `4567890`, etc., until eventually it displays the full string of data after a random number of transmits from the microcontroller.  I've never done serial in VB before so I'm bound to miss the obvious.  Am I missing something which is preventing me from receiving the whole 10 bytes every time?

Comment: In your update display you could make message class level then Message += String.Join("", RX_String).  Use a conditional to wait until it reaches the proper length then display the string.

Comment: You are making the classic mistake of ignoring the return value of the Read() method.  It will **not** be "n", usually only a few bytes.  Whatever happens to be available in the receive buffer, not much since serial ports are slow.  Don't call BeginInvoke until you got them all.

Comment: You should consider making the `UpdateDisplay` routine take the buffer as a parameter to avoid race conditions if another serial event is received before the main thread handles the previous one.  Also, `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString` is good for converting byte arrays to strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some generic code for the DataReceived event handler

```
Dim dataByts As New List(Of Byte)
Dim dataLock As New Object
Dim datarcvd As New Threading.AutoResetEvent(False)

Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As Object, _
                                     e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    Dim br As Integer = SerialPort1.BytesToRead '# of bytes to read
    If br > 0 Then
        Dim b(br - 1) As Byte 'create buffer to read into
        Try
            br = SerialPort1.Read(b, 0, b.Length) 'read the bytes
            If br < b.Length Then 'adjust length if required
                Array.Resize(b, br)
            End If
            'add bytes just read to list
            Threading.Monitor.Enter(dataLock)
            dataByts.AddRange(b)
            Threading.Monitor.Exit(dataLock)
            datarcvd.Set() 'signal event fired
            '
            'check for a condition
            '
            If dataByts.Count >= 10 Then
                'condition met <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            End If
            '
            'fine tune exception handling
            '
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SerialPort1_ErrorReceived(sender As Object, _
                                      e As IO.Ports.SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs) _
                                  Handles SerialPort1.ErrorReceived
    Debug.WriteLine(e.EventType)
End Sub
```

When you have 10 bytes (or more) then invoke the delegate and decode the string.  Note the locking when placing the bytes in the buffer.  The delegate should look like this

```
    Dim s As String = ""
    Threading.Monitor.Enter(dataLock) 'yes
    s = SerialPort1.Encoding.GetChars(dataByts.ToArray, 0, 10)
    dataByts.RemoveRange(0, 10) 'remove the bytes processed
    Threading.Monitor.Exit(dataLock)
    TextBox1.Text = s
```

Comment: Much appreciated.  I can honestly say I would never have thought of that.